# C++ Member Function Cannot Change Private Field

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, operator-overloading, sdl-2

OH! I found the problem. As I said at end, it was a simple problem.
In for loop, i iterated wiht copy of "Particle"s. I updated them but the operation does not affect the original values that stored in vector.

For requests about solution one can access the particle objects using 3 major ways.
`lvalue-ref` object way:

```
for (auto& p: particles)
    ...
```

Or by iterators:

```
for (auto it=particles.begin(); i<particles.end();++it)
    ...
```

Or by plain indexes:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<particles.size(); ++i)
    ...
```

For ones that curious about code, you may look below:

---

If I am not missing something very obvious, I encountered with a really strange problem.

To simplify the problem, I have a class named "Particle", which has a function called "update". Particle class has some private variables like position, velocity etc. And update function is supposed to make some calculations and add proper values to that private variables. But, that simply does not work.

Actually, I am sceptical about the type of that variables which is a class written by me, "Vector2".

To add values to variables, I've used the "+=" operator, and I think I implemented them correctly(?) in my Vector2 class.

To clarify situation, IMHO, it is better to give some code:

This is my Vector2.h :

```
namespace sim {

#include <ostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

struct Vector2 {
    double x, y;

    Vector2& operator+=(const Vector2& rhs) {
        this->x += rhs.x;
        this->y += rhs.y;
        cout << "op+=" << endl;
        return *this;
    }

    Vector2& operator*=(double k) {
        x *= k;
        y *= k;
        cout << "op*=" << endl;
        return *this;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Vector2& v2);
    friend Vector2 operator+(Vector2 lhs, const Vector2& rhs);
    friend Vector2 operator-(Vector2 lhs, const Vector2& rhs);
    friend Vector2 operator*(Vector2 lhs, double k);
    friend Vector2 operator*(double k, Vector2 rhs);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Vector2& v2) {
    os << "[ " << v2.x << "; " << v2.y << " ]";
    return os;
}

Vector2 operator+(Vector2 lhs, const Vector2& rhs) {
    lhs += rhs;
    cout << "op+" << endl;
    return lhs;
}

Vector2 operator*(Vector2 lhs, double k) {
    lhs *= k;
    cout << "op*" << endl;
    return lhs;
}
```

(removed some unrelated parts like constructor)

And this is Particle class:

```
class Particle {
private:
    Vector2 pos;
    Vector2 vel;
    Vector2 acc;
    double rad;
    SDL_Color clr;

public:
    Particle(
            Vector2 _p,
            Vector2 _v,
            Vector2 _a,
            double _r = 10.0,
            SDL_Color _c = { 255, 255, 255, 255 }) {

        pos = _p;
        vel = _v;
        acc = _a;

        rad = _r;
        clr = _c;
    }

    Vector2& move_particle(Vector2 move_by) {
        return (pos += move_by);
    }

    void update(double dt) {
        this->vel += acc * dt;
        this->pos += vel * dt;

        cout << "update " << pos << vel << acc << endl;
    }

    void render(SDL_Renderer* renderer) {
        // TODO: this was supposed to be a circle, but, who cares? ;)
        SDL_Rect r = { int(pos.x), int(pos.y), int(rad), int(rad) };
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &r);

        cout << "render" << endl;
    }
};
```

And the result: update does not update.

### How do I know (guess) my overloads DOES work?

For 3 `Vector2` objects, I can do any kind of operation I defined correctly.
And the results are just what they supposed to be. (Or, maybe not?)

But debugging update function roughly brings me to the point that actually += operator works for one time, and not again BUT this behaviour is showing itself only in update function.

And I know, this will be such a simple mistake that I possibly feel ashamed (just kidding).

Oh, and the main code of course:

```
int main() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    auto window = SDL_CreateWindow("My Very First Particle Simulation", -1, -1,
            1024, 768, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    auto renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    const Vector2 g(0.0, 9.8);
    double dt = 0.1;

    std::vector<Particle> particles;

    bool quit = false;
    while (!quit) {
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                quit = true;
                break;
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                particles.emplace_back(Vector2(event.button.x, event.button.y), Vector2(1.0, 0.0), g);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

            SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

            for (auto p : particles) {
                p.update(dt);
                p.render(renderer);
            }

            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, could you add a relevant portion of your stdout logging to illustrate?

Comment: Ok, it will be here in approx. 5 minutes.

Comment: Found  solution, so no need to examples. Thank you and others anyway.

Comment: So you're saying that `for (auto p : particles)` creates a copy of `particles`, or rather, `p` is a copy? What's the syntax that fixes it? Or do you need to override an iteration operator to return a ref?

Comment: @Kenney are you asking for being curious or to test me? :) Anyway, first thing came to my mind is iterators. Then, indexed access is also an option. Then blablabla.. And some other bla bla is possible too.

Comment: No I'm genuinely curious, and I also thought if you explained the problem and the solution, yours would make for a great question.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments on your code,
you can just change these to be member functions

```
friend Vector2 operator+(Vector2 lhs, const Vector2& rhs);
friend Vector2 operator-(Vector2 lhs, const Vector2& rhs);
friend Vector2 operator*(Vector2 lhs, double k);
friend Vector2 operator*(double k, Vector2 lhs);
```

as in

```
Vector2 operator+(const Vector2& rhs);
Vector2 operator-(const Vector2& rhs);
Vector2 operator*(const double k);
friend Vector2 operator*(const double k, Vector2 lhs);
```

In them copy `this` to a new `Vector2` and then update the value and return. The fourth function is kept as friend so that you can have something like double*Vector2 while the third one takes care of Vector2*double

Any operation that has Vector2 as the left operand can be done as a member function.

Comment: True for + and - operators. But I planned to handle Vector2 * Double and Double * Vector2 at the very beginning.

Comment: Exactly, that is why I didn't put this function `friend Vector2 operator*(double k, Vector2 rhs);` in my answer.

Comment: Oh, i could not get the point for multiplication. You are saying that the 3rd line of your suggestion can handle both left- and right-multiplication, right?

Comment: Nope, Basically, if `Vector2` is the left operand you can make it a member function. So Vector2*double will be handled by `Vector2 operator*(const double k);` and double*Vector2 will be handled by `friend Vector2 operator*(double k, Vector2 rhs);`. I'll update the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: OK, thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

I can see that these two operators are taking their first args by value.  Change them so the take their args by reference.

```
Vector2 operator+(Vector2 lhs, const Vector2& rhs) { // lhs should be a const reference
    lhs += rhs;
    cout << "op+" << endl;
    return lhs;
}

Vector2 operator*(Vector2 lhs, double k) { // lhs should be a const reference
    lhs *= k;
    cout << "op*" << endl;
    return lhs;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Also these functions should take their class args as `const` referenecs:

```
friend Vector2 operator+(Vector2 lhs, const Vector2& rhs);
friend Vector2 operator-(Vector2 lhs, const Vector2& rhs);
friend Vector2 operator*(Vector2 lhs, double k);
friend Vector2 operator*(double k, Vector2 rhs);
```

Comment: Tried c=a+b. Gave error `error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘sim::Vector2’ and ‘sim::Vector2’)
  auto c = a + b;`

Comment: @FatihYazıcı I updated the answer to include more changes that are needed.

Comment: @AnonMail You don't want to change those to by ref; he modifies a local copy and returns that. If you change the operator+ to take lhs by ref, then `a = b + c` will change `b`.